# What does {login} mean

Tags: wordpress, security

I have a wordpress website, there i have a plugin which shows me when a login attempt has been made way to many times.

it shows me someone has been trying to login with the username:

> {login}

failed 7 times.

What does this mean? should i be worried that someone is trying to hack the website.

Thanks in advance.

Kevin

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about WordPress programming.

Comment: Yes it's probably a bot trying to login. Whatever way no need to worry about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It simply means someone or something (a bot/script) has attempted to log into your account. Seven times is not a lot, provided you're not using extremely stupid username- and password combinations; the chance of anyone being able to access your site should be small.

If the issue continues though, you may consider applying some form of two factor authentication, such as Google Authenticator, for which a [plugin is available](https://wordpress.org/plugins/google-authenticator/). Requiring such time-limited access-codes for each login should pretty much guarantee that nobody will be able to access your site (at least not without stealing your phone first...).

Comment: Thanks for this tip.